# Use a path with unknown folder in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, path

Let's say I have this folder tree on Windows:

```
C:/
├─ random_folder_name1/
│  ├─ file1.txt
├─ random_folder_name2/
│  ├─ file2.txt
```

I don't know any folder name inside `C:\` and I want to acces to `file1.txt` in a command (ReadAllBytes for example in this case). Is there a way to do this? I would like something like that :

```
$FilePath = 'C:\*\file1.txt';
$fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath);
```

But the code above is not working and obviously says that FilePath with the '*' is not a valid format.

Comment: In general, use `Convert-Path` to convert a _PowerShell_ path into a _provider_ path that is accepted by .NET API. `$apiPath = Convert-Path 'C:\*\file1.txt' | Select-Object -First 1`. The file name might exist in multiple folders, so I have used `Select-Object` to return only the first found file.

Comment: Thanks @zett42 for clarifying this, I'll learn more about this. Yes this answer my question aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my bad I found the answer just after posting this... (I searched before)

replace `$FilePath = 'C:\*\file1.txt';` with `$FilePath = Resolve-Path -Path 'C:\*\file1.txt';`

Answer (score 1):

You can search for files and get the path back like this

```
gci -recurse -filter 'filename' -Path "C:\"
```

To get back only the path, you can add the following

```
gci -recurse -filter 'filename' -Path "C:\" | %{$_.FullName}
```